# Why am I getting ModuleNotFoundError openpyxl

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and my code runs within the Pycharm IDE without any error. However, if I running it from the Windows command prompt, it terminates with the following error:

```
 from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I am using python 3.9.5 on Windows 10 and I have successfully performed "pip install openpyxl" from Window's command line.

The code:

```
import openpyxl
.............
.............
data = someFunction()
data.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Despite the error, the openpyxl is in **C:\Users\me\Documents\Python\PythonLearning\venv\Lib\site-packages**. The system PATH environment variable points to **installationDir\python39** and **installationDir\python39\Scripts**. In addition, I have added **C:\Users\me\Documents\Python\PythonLearning\venv\Lib\site-packages** to the PATH. The **C:\Users\me\Documents\Python\PythonLearning** is my project folder. I also have the **Lib** folder from the **Python** installation directory **C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib** in the PATH. Despite all, the **import openpyxl** still throws an error when running the code from the command-line prompt.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: have you added all the python related paths to the environment variables? I believe pycharm discovers the packages automatically, but that's not the case with python on CMD.

Comment: @samkart: Honestly, I started learning Python yesterday, so I am not sure what other environment variables I need to add besides 'installationDir\python39\' and 'installationDir\python39\Scripts\'?

Comment: afaik, there should be a `Lib` folder as well. Check if the package folder is indeed in that folder. I think the paths you have added currently are good to go.

Comment: you probably need to activate the venv before running the program. try `C:\Users\me\Documents\Python\PythonLearning\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

Comment: @samkart, by package folder, do you mean the project package? I have a directory structure C:\Users\hrh74\me\Python\PythonLearning\venv\Lib\site-packages, where my source code resides in PythonLearning folder. I have added C:\Users\hrh74\me\Python\PythonLearning\venv\Lib\site-packages to the PATH but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @Altareos: Thanks a lot, indeed the activate was the problem. Please make it an Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing Python packages in a virtual environment, or venv, you need to run the `activate` script before launching the python executable.

In your case:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\Python\PythonLearning\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

This tripped me up the other day:

```
data.to_excel('test.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
```

Comment: I added the 'engine' parameter but the 'import openpyxl' still gives me the same error when running the code from the command-line

Comment: Did you put the quotes around 'openpyxl'?  That's what got me...

Comment: I have==>   data.to_excel('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')